# Shell.Execute in VBA is not doing anything

Tags: vba, powershell

I am trying to use powershell to extract some files from a zip folder located on a drive where I only have read access to my desktop in a temp folder where I can do whatever I like to them.

Using the code below I get no errors but the powershell code just does nothing.
Am I missing something?

```
Sub unzip_test()
    Dim myshell As Shell32.Shell
    Set myshell = New Shell32.Shell

    Dim args As String
    args = "Expand-Archive -LiteralPath " & "'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\TEMP\examplezip.zip'" & " -destinationpath " & "'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\TEMP\tester'"
    'Debug.Print (args)
    myshell.ShellExecute "powershell", vargs:=args

End Sub
```

The debug.print prints `Expand-Archive -LiteralPath 'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\TEMP\examplezip.zip' -destinationpath 'C:\Users\st11524\Desktop\TEMP\tester'`

Also, I have "Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation" checked in my references.

Answer (score 1):

It should work. I think the problem is somewhere in the Expand-Archive call, but you can't see the answer.
The quick fix is to add `-NoExit` to your call, like this

```
args = "-NoExit Expand-Archive -LiteralPath " ...
```

This will allow you to read the error before it closes, but you can't read it from your code. If you need that, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53434803/powershell-invoke-command-exchange-mgmt-shell-from-vba-with-stdout-and-stderr-re)

Comment: When I run the code I had listed powershell doesn't even pop up. Adding the -noexit does not stop it from closing because it never opened. I also just noticed I get a windows sound when I run the vba. Still nothing though.

Answer (score 0):

After testing this on another computer I've come to the conclusion that this is a permissions thing. My personal computer runs the script just fine where my work computer won't. I don't see anything wrong with the code listed above so I will consider this issue resolved.

Comment: Interesting. It would help others if you clarified what the specific permission issue is (assuming you know).

Comment: Would also like to see what you may come up with as this scenario should be quite common. If everything fails, the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` should do. That's what I used for zipping in my project [VBA.Compress](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Compress).

Comment: mklement0: Sadly I do not know what permission is breaking this function.
Gustav: thank you, I have used that before and I can get it to work in other ways but I was just interested in the PowerShell aspect of getting this to work. Less code and more interesting IMO. Thanks for the suggestion!